# Finding the index of element in a list of lists

Tags: prolog

I have this data structure where the elements are always unique:

```
[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [y,z]]
```

Now, I want to write a procedure to get the index of an element, say I have:

```
indexOf([[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [y,z]], a, H)
```

and `H` is `0`. Or:

```
indexOf([[a,b,c], [d,e,f], [y,z]], f, H)
```

and `H` is `2`.

This is what I have:

```
indexOf_single([X|_],X,0).
indexOf_single([_|T],X,H) :- indexOf_single(T,X,H1), H is H1 + 1.

indexOf([T],X,H) :- indexOf_single(T,X,H).
indexOf([Head|Tail],X,H) :- indexOf_single(Head,X,H),indexOf(Tail,X,H).
```

But I'm getting `false` all the time. Could you please give me any clues to solve it?

Comment: Do you know what fails? Which of the two predicates is it? And do you know of `nth0/3`? You can use it to replace your `indexOf_single/3`, if you are using a Prolog implementation that has it. It is also possible that it has `nth/3`; then, use `nth(Index1, List, Element), succ(Index, Index1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
indexOf([Head|_],X,H) :- indexOf_single(Head,X,H).
indexOf([_|Tail],X,H) :- indexOf(Tail,X,H).
```

I see two errors in your `indexOf/3`.

(1) in your second clause

```
indexOf([Head|Tail],X,H) :- indexOf_single(Head,X,H),indexOf(Tail,X,H).
```

you ask that `H` is found in the `Head` (via `indexOf_single/3`) **and** in the `Tail`. And this is impossible when "the elements are always unique".

(2) in your first clause

```
indexOf([T],X,H) :- indexOf_single(T,X,H).
```

you search in `T` **only** if `T` is the last sub-list of the first argument.

Comment: yeah works! thanks a lot. Could you please explain how you made this change?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani - answer improved; hope this helps.